# I deleted all MySQL connections, and new ones don't work

Tags: mysql

I'm learning SQL via MySQL, and wanted to play around MySQL connections, in order to learn that concept. I deleted all existing ones, and tried creating a new one with the following settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzdG8.png)

But, when I click on it, I get the following error:
"Your connection attempt failed for user 'admin' to the MySQL server at 127.0.0.1:3306". Access Denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NraCU.png)

I tried to change Connection Method to "Local Socket/Pipe" and still got the same error.
I also tried this terminal command `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306` with no results.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oej4i.png)

Any suggestions?

---

Update:
I created a new connection with `root` as username and `TCP/IP` as a connection method. I successfully connected using a password I set upon installation. How is this possible when I created new connection from scratch?

Comment: If you do have an `admin` user, did you set a password on it? If you did then the connection will need that password

Comment: I updated the original post with the output of terminal command.

Comment: I managed to successfully log in with completely new connection, using password I set up during the installation. How is this password tied to a new connection I just created? I'm confused

Comment: You are connecting with a user account. Its not just making a conduit, it needs to know if you are allowed to make the connection

Answer (score 0):

Need to set a **password**, you can click clean first, and then enter the password to test whether the connection is available. In addition, it is recommended to use a specific ip address instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. You need to create `root@‘%'` user.

Answer (score 0):

the error is that MySqlWorkbench is trying to connect with `admin` user not `root` user, are you sure the admin user already exist?
you can try to connect with root user from MysqlWorkbench or create the `admin` user
`CREATE USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD_HERE';`